# Detecting hair color in a portrait image

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation

Ok, assuming that I have correctly working the alghoritm that detect and encapsulate the hair of a portrait picture.

How can i (witha a high % correctness), differentiate between colors?

I know it seems simple, but the main problem is that depending on either the environment light conditions of where the picture were taken or (the less cases) post effect processing, a range of "blond", "black", "brown" and "red" change a lot, given false positive and some times no detecting correct ones. (Passing a blonde as black fore example).

Using opencv (or any other tool, because I already have the hair), which pre processing algorithm or methods should I apply to "normalize" this kind of problems and minimize errors?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To differentiate colors, the HSV color space is usually a good option because you can directly get the hue.

Comment: you solved the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use machine learning methods for color classification.
Just train classifier (e.g. SVM or neural network) on hear color samples (you can take color histogram as input vector), and some classes (color names). I think it will be good method fo deal with light changes, noise, shadows, etc. And I think it'll be better use some advanced color space  L*a*b* or HSV.

May be you will need include in input vector some reference historgam (for get data about lighting conditions). You can get it from face for example (not the best solution).

Comment: Thanks, i have read a little more, and in fact i should use (as on option) YCbCr, omiting Y.
Taking some samples of the hair color ranges and having them in th YCbCr space then compared with the isolated (also in YCbCr) hair of each picture.
Am i right?
thanks

Comment: No, I mean for example: you have color histogram vector {1,2,3,42,4,2,6} and you assign label e.g. "yellow". You have a lot of such pairs. Then you can train classifier using this data. And after training it will get from you histogram vector and give you color name.

Comment: Here you can read about using ML in similar problem: http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2009/VSVL09/verbeek09tip.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you can do any pre-processing just using the hair area. I'm saying this just by intuition.

Here is an idea. Histogram equalization is a famous pre-processing method that overcomes illumination effects to some amount. So what you can do is, separate your image into color channels, apply histogram equalization to each of the channels, and then combine the channels to get the histogram equalized image. I think that it would be useful.

I've implemented it on Matlab, tried it on Lena. You can download it from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14588321/color_hist_eq.zip) (*dead link*).

Comment: Your link does not work anymore, could you update it?